# java garbage collector does not work as expected

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

my question is simple.. if you run the following program on any machine the heap will get full quickly. so why GC is not fast enough to free the memory.
and when the heap is full with all 
'new unused objects'. why they will stick in the heap !!

```
public class TestGc {

public String name;

public TestGc next;

public TestGc(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static TestGc create(String nm, int len) {
    TestGc[] tmp = new TestGc[len];
    TestGc prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TestGc cur = new TestGc(nm + i);
        tmp[i] = cur;
        if (prev != null)
            prev.next = cur;

        prev = cur;
    }
    return tmp[0];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: TestGc <number of roots");
        return;
    }

    int num = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    TestGc[] arr = new TestGc[num];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 1000; i++, j++) {
        if (j == num)
            j = 0;
        String nm = "root_" + i + "_";
        System.out.println("******** " + nm);
        arr[j] = create(nm, 1000000);
    }
    double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;
    System.out.println("******** duration " + duration + " sec.");
}
```

}

```
java -Xmx23g -Xms23g -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails TestGc 150
```

the example is copied from here.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065402

Comment: Because you assign the `TestGc` instance(s) to `arr` they are still reachable on every iteration of your loop. **Why** do you want to this?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because all objects except array referenced by `tmp` in `create` method are reachable, so they should not be disposed by GC.